# Azure Pipelines: Select branch for git-submodule

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules

I've an environment which makes use of git submodules.

When making a change in the underlying submodule-repo I've always to create a branch on top level, make a change in the submodule reference and push it to server. Then I'm ready to run a pipeline with needed commit of the submodule.

In order to make this easier, I would like to have the possibility to select a branch or commit of the submodule when starting the build on top level.

On jenkins, I used to use an optional parameter created by https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/ to select a branch of the submodule.

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything like that for Azure Pipelines. In the list of [Parameter data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#parameter-data-types) I've found `type: string` only, which is quite simplistic compared to what I've had in jenkins.

Logic would be:

```
IF parameter for submodule branch is set
THEN 
$ cd submodule_path
$ git checkout --detach <optional branch>
```

Is there any easy or build-in solution for this task? I would appreciate a dropdown parameter list instead of adding the branch name manually.

I know that this approach has drawbacks in terms of reproducibility and traceability, but benefits for hands-on testing are quite large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to configure the YAML pipeline like as below:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: 'Select submodule branch'
  type: string
  default: branch01
  values:
  - branch01
  - branch02
  - branch03

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: 'Build'
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
  . . .
  
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Select submodule branch'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        cd submodule_path
        git checkout --detach ${{ parameters.SubmoduleBranch }}

  . . .
```

Then, when manually triggering the pipeline, you can see the window like as below and select one of the listed branches on the window.

[image]

For more details, you can reference the document "[**Runtime parameters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was searching more on an option where the list of branches is automatically created.

Comment: additionally it seems that I need to run a `git fetch` before the checkout, which brings me into trouble with credentials. did your example work on your end?

Comment: Hi @amw, The sample in my above answer is just guide you how to use the parameter to set the submodule branch you want and use the parameter in the pipeline task. For the detailed git command lines you require, you just need to use the same git command lines that you used on your local machine to check out the submodule branch.

Comment: In addition, as far as I know, it is not possible to dynamically and automatically fetch the submodule branches and set them to the values list of parameter. When you add a new branch in the submodule repo, you need to manually update the values list of parameter in the YAML.